# Error when running Access 2003 app in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

My organization is in the process of upgrading from Access 2003 to Access 2007. One of the apps I am tasked with upgrading is returning very odd errors while opening and closing forms that have nested forms. Have the events changed between Access 2003 and Access 2007 ? The events seem to be firing in a different order in 2007 then they did in 2003.

Comment: I have also encountered strange problems which seem to be related to the order of events with subforms.  They are not consistent, and I have never found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't encountered the situation you described.  I can't find anything which mentions changes to forms event model.  Allen Browne has some information about Access 2007 compatibility with older versions:
http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html#Compatibility

The only problems I experienced so far with 2003 MDBs in Access 2007 were due to broken references.  If you haven't already done so, double-check yours (Tools-> References) from the VB editor.  While there, try Debug -> Compile to verify whether your code will compile without errors in Access 2007.

Tony Toews' *Corrupt Microsoft Access MDBs FAQ* could help fix or rule out odd behavior due to corruption:

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm

If you've done those things, and still have problems with certain forms, it might be useful to create a new blank database and import those forms (and objects they depend on) into the new database.

Sorry to scatter-shot this thing.  It might help if you could provide more detail about the nature of the errors you're getting.

Comment: This doesn't look like corruption to me.